# Convert javac command from .sh to .bat

Tags: batch-file, javac, sh

Hi i have difficulties trying to translate this .sh file to a .bat file.

```
javac -cp $tomcatpath/servlet-api.jar:$openejbpath/javaeeapi-5.0-3.jar 
$webapppath/*.java $webapppath/bean/*.java $webapppath/ejb/*.java
```

It should be really simple for someone familiar with these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
javac -cp %tomcatpath%/servlet-api.jar;%openejbpath%/javaeeapi-5.0-3.jar 
%webapppath%/*.java %webapppath%/bean/*.java %webapppath%/ejb/*.java
```

Answer (score 0):

```
javac -cp $tomcatpath\servlet-api.jar;$openejbpath\javaeeapi-5.0-3.jar 
$webapppath\*.java $webapppath\bean\*.java $webapppath\ejb\*.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the ensure that the tomcatpath, openejbpath and webapppath environment variables are setup correctly in your Windows installation. Use the commands

```
set tomcatpath=c:\path\to\tomcat
set openejbpath=c:\path\to\openejb 
set webapppath=c:\path\to\webapp
```

Then run the command as

```
javac -cp %tomcatpath%\servlet-api.jar;%openejbpath%\javaeeapi-5.0-3.jar %webapppath%\*.java %webapppath%\bean\*.java %webapppath%\ejb\*.java
```

Of course, if you want to use cross-platform build scripts, you should really be using Ant - http://ant.apache.org/